# Python: Searching for a sublist within a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am analysing a table of the following sort:

```
Label   Measurement_1   Measurement_2   ...   Measurement_N
```

Now, I am given an array that contains a subset of the measurements given in the table. What I want to achieve is: Take the subset of measurements, find where each subitem is in my table, and return the corresponding label.

This should be straightforward using a simple for-loop, I figured. So I read in my table as a 2D numpy-array. I have the sublist as a numpy-array as well:

```
corresponding_idx = []
for measurement in sublist:
    for i in range(0, myTable.shape[0]):
        if measurement == myTable[i,:]:
            corresponding_idx.append(i)

corresponding_labels = []
for idx in corresponding_idx:
    corresponding_labels.append(myTable[i,0])
```

I really thought this would work. But the code fails, claiming:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So. I understand that my comparison `measurement == myTable[i,:]` is causing the issue. I am trying to find the row in `myTable` that corresponds to `measurement`. 
I thought, maybe just change the line to `measurement.all() == myTable[i].all()` . But doing so results in my `corresponding_idx` list being insanely large.

I am lost. Can somebody help?

Comment: I would be helpful if your question included a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: is your table a pandas dataframe or other format of data?

Answer (score 0):

The statement `measurement == myTable[i,:]` returns a boolean array. If you'd want to check that the whole subarray equals `measurement`, you should wrap the statement with `np.all()`.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your table is a pandas data frame you can do:

```
corresponding_labels=[]
for row in sublist:
  corresponding_idx = myTable.index[(myTable[myTable.columns[1:]]==row).all(axis=1)]
  corresponding_labels.append(myTable.loc[corresponding_idx, 'Label'].values[0])
```

I am also pretty sure you can do it without loop too (probably by converting pandas to array)